# execlp command doesn't take into account the asterisk wildcard

Tags: c, unix, command

this little command :

```
execlp("/bin/echo", "echo", "*", ">", "toto", 0)
```

prints `* > toto` in the terminal, but I want it to print the result of `echo *` in the file toto.

The command : `system("echo * > toto")`  works well, but I want to use the execlp command, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think `execlp` attempts to execute the command `echo` directly. TO do what you want the command needs to go to the shell/command interpretor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle bracket ('>') redirection is shell specific.

You could do, for example:

```
execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/echo * > toto", NULL);
```

Note that this invokes 2 specific behaviors that are shell related:

1. * wildcard: the asterisk wildcard will be expanded (**by the shell**, very important) to all files in current directory; and
2. > redirection: the stdout of the `echo` command will be redirected to file (or pipe) `toto`.

If you want to do the same kind of redirection in C (i.e. without resorting to executing the shell) you must:

```
// open the file
int fd = open("toto", "w");

// reassign your file descriptor to stdout (file descriptor 1):
dup2(fd, 1); // this will first close file descriptor, if already open

// optionally close the original file descriptor (as it were duplicated in fd 1 and is not needed anymore):
close(fd);

// finally substitute the running image for another one:
execlp("/bin/echo", "echo", "*" 0);
```

Note that you'll still get '*' written to the file.

**Edit:** the first argument to `execlp` is really the executable to run, file image that will substitute the currently running process. After this first argument comes the full `argv` array, which must include `argv[0]`.  I've edited the code above to reflect this. Some programs use this `argv[0]` to change its personality (for example, `busybox` is a single executable that implements `ls`, `echo`, `cat` and many other unix command line utilities); that surely is the case with `bash` and whatever is linked from `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! If I run this command : execlp("/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/echo", "*", ">", "toto", (char *) 0); I have the following error : /bin/echo: 1: /bin/echo: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")") and if I replace sh by bash, I have this error : /bin/echo: /bin/echo: cannot execute binary file, do you know why?

Comment: @user3683807 I corrected the call to execlp; both /bin/sh and /bin/bash expect a single argument for '-c'; they'll parse the command line themselves.

Comment: I tried a lot of similar commands, but it still doesn't work with execlp("/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/echo * > toto", NULL); I have the following error : -c: 0: Can't open /bin/echo * > toto, any idea? Moreover, I think that I didn't really understand what the option "-c" does...

Comment: @user3683807, the "-c" argument to shell interpreter means "don't expect commands from keyboard, but instead read them from the next argument following -c".

Comment: @user3683807, usually /bin/sh is a symbolic link to /bin/bash (well, even then bash behaves differently when it detects its argv[0] to be "sh"); in my system (Debian) it is a symlink to /bin/dash. I think bash and dash (and both when invoked as sh) all accept "-c" argument.

Comment: @user3683807, you could try typing it in your terminal session (the same you use to launch your program): "/bin/sh -c 'echo *'" (yes, the apostrophes around 'echo *' is really needed); see what happens.

Comment: if I type this, it gives me the same result as "echo *"

Comment: @user3683807, now I got it: you need to duplicate the argument "/bin/sh". I'll edit the answer to explain this.